# java.lang.stackoverflowerror on small import

Tags: neo4j

I am doing some work with neo4j based around working out who knows who and what they do, it is in the format of

Company-node
product-node
person-node

and the relationships between them as

company borders,by location

person works at company

company has product.

I have a spreadsheet that has all the information written down and a macro that takes the iformation adn converts it into cypher. THe code comes to around 5000 lines.

When I try to import it I get an unknown error if I try to run it in the internet browser. If i run it in the shell it goes the whole way through and then gives the error

Error occurre in server thread ; nested exception is:
    java.lang.StackOverflowerror

my heap size is set to 3gb

anyone have any ideas on what the error is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist of all it has nothing to do with your heap size, it is related to stack size. if you want to increase stack size use -Xss parameter.
 Also stack is used to hold intermediate variables and function calls, your import is somehow crossing the stack size set in you configuration.

Comment: What size do you think this should be set at within the jvm settings if there is 1800 nodes and 3400 relationships and about 8000 properties within the nodes and relationships?

Comment: Hi m not sure of the exact configuration..it needs to be fine tuned gradually. This is similar to configuring the no of threads in a thread pool

Comment: To set the properties for the jvm would I add these in the java control panel in the control panel -> programs->java in windows, Apologies for the continuing questions I'm relatively new at this

Comment: No This is a startup configuration just like -Xmx and -Xms. Say if you are working in tomcat search for Xmx and just append -xss=512M. This will be picked on startup.